# Is it possible to get enum types store them in a collection in Swift 4?

Tags: swift, enums, swift4

I have multiple Enum types that conform to a specific protocol and I want to store their types in a single array. But I can't seem to find the way to do it.

Here is the simplified code.

```
protocol TestEnumProtocol {
    static var name: String { get }
    static var count: Int { get }
}

enum Test1 : TestEnumProtocol {
    static var name: String { return "Test1" }
    static var count: Int { return 2 }

    case A
    case B
}

enum Test2 : TestEnumProtocol {
    static var name: String { return "Test2" }
    static var count: Int { return 3 }

    case AA
    case BB
    case CC
}

var enums: [TestEnumProtocol.self] = [Test1.self, Test2.self] // Compile Error
```

Basically there are multiple multivariate testings I need to handle and I want to make my logic generic.

I know I can achieve this by using classes, but I'm wondering if there is a way with enums because Enum seems to be more intuitive in this context. (at least for me)

Comment: `var enums: [Any] = [Test1.self, Test2.self]` or `var enums: [TestEnumProtocol] = [Test1.A, Test2.BB]` You need an instance of enum in the 2nd case ;)

Comment: Changing `TestEnumProtocol.self` to `TestEnumProtocol.Type` eliminates the error.

Comment: @sloik, rmaddy thank you so much for your response! and .Type solution works the best in this context :)